# WEBページ上のミニマップの作成に関する情報もとむ

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

よくゲームとかで自分がマップのどこに居るか、画面上に小さくミニマップみたいのが出てたりしますよね？
それのwebページ版のような、
・webページの全体像を縮小し
・現在ウィンドウに映っている範囲がどこかを表示する
「ミニマップ」を、webページ上に表示したいです。
それを実装するためのjavascriptかjqueryの情報を求めています。

何かお知りの方いましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

完全な縮小されたWebページではないですが、

https://github.com/lrsjng/pagemap

Comment: ありがとうございます。このようなもので十分です。試したところうまくいきました。大変助かりました